# How can I make an animation of objects being sucked in like a vacuum cleaner?

Tags: animation

I need to create an animation of a vacuum cleaner, which sucks objects (coins) into itself.

Here's the reference of vacuuming I need to create:

[image]

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UDIC5wVY9qIi-4rD4kLeqb0udtoDNU7h?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about the animation itself... it's not everyday that we use a vacuum cleaner to suck coins...

Comment: Could you do it in reverse? Have coins spat out of the vacuum cleaner, then play the video in reverse?

Answer (score 13):

You could create a cylinder (*Rigid Body > Type > Passive, Shape > Mesh*), a *Force Field* inside the cylinder (*Type > Force*, *Strength > -600* or whatever), the coins (*Rigid Body > Type > Active*), an invisible funnel that will help to move the coins towards the cylinders (*Rigid Body > Type > Passive, Shape > Mesh*), and of course the floor (*Rigid Body > Type > Passive*):

[image]

Comment: nice, but only feasible for a few rigid bodies. What happens, if the animation should last longer and suck in hundreds of cubes? i think then you could be soon in trouble ;)

Comment: @Chris perhaps nothing that couldn't be fixed with some invisible funnels,  nudged judiciously :) Or.. maybe, shooting in reverse? ... hard to say, without knowing the shot/style.

Comment: Sure, a storyboard would help   ;)

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain how to create the invisible funnel? It is just a shape or something else?

Comment: I added a link for the reference. Please, have a look

Comment: So maybe tell in what way what I show would or would not work?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for long distance. They all stuck in the tube and doesn't move.

Comment: Yes but it all depends on your storyboard

Answer (score 9):

A more cartoonish approach could be like this:

[image]

Geometry node simulation.

[image]

It starts with points distributed inside a volume.

Store a random rotation on these points (it will be used later).

Calculate the distance between points and an empty. If this distance is less than a given value, mark the instances as "moving'.

The movement itself is to go to the empty given a float curve and to scale down the radius so that all these so many coins are able to fit inside of the vacuum tube.

Last, if the distance is short, delete the point.

After the simulation, instanciate the coins on the points with the random rotation calculated and stored at the begining.

[image] (Blender 4.0)

Comment: Nice: looks like a story-board to steal bitcoin from an online bank!

Comment: Thank you!!! is it posible to add phisics to all of them? I want them to collide with each other, react to others movement

Comment: Not easily at all with geometry nodes, for now. But for "full" simulation improving on what proposed moonboots should work.